# to create Secure RDP using a Windows Bastion Host server

Tags: google-cloud-platform, rdp

Topics tested
Create a new VPC to host secure production Windows services.

Create a Windows host connected to a subnet in the new VPC with an internal only network interface.

Create a Windows bastion host (jump box) in with an externally accessible network interface.

Configure firewalls rules to enable management of the secure Windows host from the Internet using the bastion host as a jump box.

Setup

this is a qwiklabs problem

Comment: What is the question and what is the problem you are trying to solve?

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a VPC network  with one subnet(custom)
2. Create a FW rule with a 'RDPtag' and protocol (TCP:3389) in the subnet created
3. Create a Windows VM-(vm-bastionhost) with 2 network interfaces 
   a. with custom subnet created. Select External IP to be Ephemeral. 
   b. with Default network. Select External IP to be none. 
   Add the network tag -'RDPtag'
4. Create a Windows VM (vm-securehost) with 2 network interfaces 
   a. with custom subnet created. Select External IP to be none. 
   b. with Default network. Select External IP to be none.
   Add the network tag -'RDPtag'
5. Reset the credentials for both the VM's. Use

gcloud compute reset-windows-password vm-bastionhost --user app_admin --zone us-central1-a

gcloud compute reset-windows-password vm-securehost --user app_admin --zone us-central1-a

6. RDP in the vm- bastionhost using the new credentials.
7. From the vm-bastionhost machine, mstsc to the vm-securehost using new credentials.

Install IIS in vm-securehost.